# What is wrong with this proof that if $V = U_1 \oplus W$ and if $V = U_2 \oplus W$, then $U_1 = U_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

> **Claim:** Let $U_1, U_2$ and $W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Suppose $V = U_1 \oplus W$ and $V = U_2 \oplus W$. Then $U_1 = U_2$.

**"Proof"**

Let $v \in V$.

Then $\exists \space u_1 \in U_1 $ and $w_1 \in W$ such that $v=u_1+w_1 \space \space \space (1)$

Also, $\exists \space u_2 \in U_2$ and $w_2 \in W$ such that $v=u_2+w_2 \space \space \space (2)$

$(1) - (2) \implies 0 = (u_1 - u_2) + (w_1 - w_2)$. Here, $(u_1 - u_2) \in U_1 \cup U_2$ and $w = (w_1 - w_2) \in W$.

Under a direct sum, the only representation for $0$ is, $0 = 0 + 0$, where the first $0 \in U_1 \cup U_2$ and the second $0 \in W$.

Therefore, $u_1 - u_2 = 0 \implies u_1 = u_2 \implies u_1 \in U_2 \implies U_1 \subset U_2$. Similarly, $u_2 \in U_1 \implies U_2 \subset U_1$. Hence, $U_1 = U_2$.

**Q.E.D**

But I'm aware of counterexamples in which $U_1 \neq U_2$. So can anyone tell me where the above "proof" breaks down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem in this proof is assuming that

> $(u_1 - u_2) \in  U_1 \cup U_2$.

In vector spaces, $u_1 \in U_1$ and $u_2 \in U_2$ do not imply $u_1 - u_2 \in U_1 \cup U_2$. In fact, it is more likely that $u_1 - u_2 \notin U_1 \cup U_2$.

There is another minor flaw:

> $ u_1 \in U_2 \implies U_1 \subset U_2 $.

This is true if it holds for every $u_1 \in U_1$, but in this case you cannot pick $u_1$ freely since $u_1$ is determined as $v$ is picked. In this case, you can prove that every vector in $U_1$ can be $u_1$, but that is not written in your proof.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! Thank you. But may I ask how you say that every vector in $U_1$ can be $u_1$? I mean, for a given $v$, there is only a unique representation, isn't it?

Comment: Let $u$ an arbitrary vector of $U_1$ and let $v = u$. Then because $v = u + 0$ has an unique representation as a sum of an element of $U_1$ and an element of $W$, $u_1$ must be $u$ and $w=0$. Hence $u = u_1 \in U_2$ for every $u \in U_1$.

Comment: But why must $u_1 \in U_2$? There could be another $u_2 \in U_2$ which represents $u$.

Comment: I don't see why you even need $u_1-u_2\in U_1\cup U_2$. You have shown that $u_1-u_2=0$ so that $u_1=u_2$. Having this though doesn't show that $U_1=U_2$.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown that every element of $U_1$ is in $U_2$ or vice verse. Your $u_1$ and $u_2$ aren't arbitrary.